# A function of which $n(x)$-times derivative vanashes for all $x$ is a polynomial?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Suppose $f\colon\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ is a function such that $\forall x\in\mathbb R,\exists n\in\mathbb Z_{\ge0},D^nf(x)=0$ where $D^nf$ is the $n$-th derivative of $f$ at $x$. Is it always the case that $f$ is a polynomial? (false, see edit)

The case when $f$ is $C^\infty$ [follows from](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Th%C3%A9or%C3%A8me_de_Baire#Quelques_applications) Baire's category theorem (a solution in English could be found [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/34067)). However, what if it's only assumed to be differentiable $n(x)$-times at $x$?

**EDIT:**

As Christian Blatter pointed out, it's generally false. I wonder whether there are results to control the set of bad points. Let $S$ be the set of $x$ such that $f$ isn't a polynomial in a neighborhood of $x$. It follows from Baire's category theorem that $S$ is a closed set with empty interior. Christian's comment could be extended so that $S$ is countable. However, I wonder whether $S$ could be dense or uncountable, or even of positive measure.

Comment: Let $f(x):\equiv0$ when $x\leq0$ and $f(x):=x^2$ when $x\geq0$.